# How can I target a specific element that shares a class name?

Tags: jquery

I have a series of images on my site that all share a common class. As I scroll the window down, I want to fade in *only* the image that is currently within the viewport.

What I have is working, but so far its an all or nothing. Once the first image enters the viewport, all images fade in. Ideally, I'd like to have them fade in one by one as they enter the viewport.

I am scrolling a div - not the actual window using `overflow-y: scroll;`

I have tried using the [viewport](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) plugin, but I am still getting the same result.

Here is the jQuery I am using to listen to the scroll + fade in the image(s). I understand why it's doing all at once - I'm just hung on how to separate out each image from the array of images (class).

```
$('.section-container section:nth-child(2)').scroll(function () {
    $('.img-chart').each(function (key, val) {
        var $chart = $(val); // Give me a jquery object of the element(s).
        var src = $chart.prop('src');

        if (isInView($chart)) {
            console.log('in view: ' + $chart); // this is returning every image. I would like to get only the one that is currently in the viewport.
            // Do stuff with the $chart element.    
        }
    });
});


var isInView = function ($element) {
    var win = $(window);
    var obj = $element;
    var scrollPosition = win.scrollTop();
    var visibleArea = win.scrollTop() + win.height();
    var objEndPos = (obj.offset().top + obj.outerHeight());

    return (visibleArea >= objEndPos && scrollPosition <= objEndPos ? true : false)
};
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

I' have updated my script to remove the plugin. Maybe that will help expose my flaw.

**EDIT 2**

It seems it is seeing when a specific image is in viewport. 
As soon as I scroll I see this (logging what is in view).

```
in view: http://farmersdeliver.dev/assets/img/img01.png
in view: http://farmersdeliver.dev/assets/img/img02.png
in view: http://farmersdeliver.dev/assets/img/img03.png
```

This is causing all images with that class to fade in. When I continue to scroll to where the image actually is in view, I get this:

```
[21] in view: http://farmersdeliver.dev/assets/img/img01.png
in view: http://farmersdeliver.dev/assets/img/img02.png
in view: http://farmersdeliver.dev/assets/img/img03.png
```

"21" being the log event of course. So its seeing it correctly. I just don't have the logic correct to not show everything right away or something...

Comment: Is the ':in-viewport' selector valid? I thought these selectors were reserved according to http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: You are correct - it is not. It's a selector from the plugin. IDK if I want to keep using it or not.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about `$.each` is that `this` gets bound to the current element in the iterator.

```
$('.img-chart:in-viewport').each(function (key, val) {
    if ($(this).offset().top + < $(window).scrollTop()) { // If top of element is in view
        // Your other conditions
        $(this).show(); //Or whatever you need to do
    }
});
```

Finding whether an element is in view is as simple as checking its offset against the scroll of the window.

Comment: But OP is using `var $chart = $(val);` which is the same as `var $chart = $(this);`